# Subject repeating in a why question

Tags: grammar

May I have some clarification as to why this question requires "it" to be properly constructed?

"Why isn't it easy for you to earn money? "

"it" in this case being the act of earning money. I am confused as to why the subject needs to be mentioned twice.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a simpler expression:

> For you to earn money isn't easy.

That sentence has a subordinate clause *for you to earn money* as subject, and it is connected (negatively) to the adjective *easy*.

English usually uses **subject extraposition** to change this to

> It isn't easy for you to earn money.

That puts the subordinate clause that was the subject at the end of the sentence, where it is easier to understand, and puts the adjective **easy** in front of it.
English syntax needs a dummy subject before the verb, and **it** serves that purpose.

The word **it** occurs in your sentence for the same reason:

> Why isn't it easy for you to earn money?

The sentence *It isn't easy for you to earn money* is made into a subordinate clause in the question, and the verb *isn't* precedes the subject *it* because that is a way to make it a question.

For more information, see
[Thoughco "Extraposition in Grammar"](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626)

Answer (score -2):

The sentence you quote is incorrect. It should be, "Why is it not easy for you to earn money?"
Sometimes when people use a contraction, the sentence sounds too short, too abrupt, and so they add unnecessary words to fill it out.
Two examples of this come to mind. One is the example you give. "Why isn't it ..." If you expand the contraction, it would be, "Why is it not it ..." which is obviously wrong. But "pack" the "it" into a contraction and the sentence "feels" too abrupt.
Another example I hear a lot: "Where's it at?" What they meanis, "Where is it?" But because they put the "is" into a contraction, "Where's it?" seems too abrupt, so they add the unnecessary word "at".
If you use a contraction and a sentence seems too abrupt, "unpack" the contraction. Don't add unnecessary or redundant words.

Comment: "Why isn't it ..." would expand to "Why is it not..." not  "Why is it not it ..." In English you can't always substitute a contraction for the expanded version.